# how to draw custom lands for OSM

Tags: editor, openstreetmap

I would like to know how to draw custom lands for an Openstreetmap project. My final purpose is to reproduce a fantasy map with OSM technology.
It's not clear to me how I can generate lands data (continents, islands and so on).
I know is it possible because the project https://opengeofiction.net/ do basically the same thing.

I am a new OSM user and I am moving the firsts steps with GIS software.
I have built my own tile server on the cloud (Ubuntu 18-04) following different tutorials.
I installed JOSM and QGIS to edit maps, but I feel a bit lost with all that options and features.
I already posted questions in openstreetmap forum but I got no response.
I am sure I need only a little hint to get started.

My expected result is to be able to draw a little "imaginary" island.

Comment: Deploying the full OSM rendering / editing stack is probably overkill for your project. Instead, think about using a singe software such as QGIS for editing and rendering your own little project. This should significantly reduce complexity.

Answer (score 1):

On a small scale you can use JOSM without OSM download/upload, and just save your edited data locally as an OSM XML file.

That again can then be fed into the different renderers as source file.

On a large scale you would end up creating a copy of the whole OSM stack, serving your own data, like https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OpenGeofiction does